# SSAS-Cube Creation error-deployement

Tags: reporting-services, ssis, ssas, cube

Can anyone tell me why do i get this error and how to fix it???

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qPQFW.png)

SampleCube2
      
      ProcessFull
      UseExisting
    
  

    Processing Database 'SampleCube2' completed.
        Processing Dimension 'Dim Currency' completed.
            Start time: 4/6/2016 11:16:22 AM; End time: 4/6/2016 11:16:22 AM; Duration: 0:00:00
            Processing Dimension Attribute '(All)' completed.
                Start time: 4/6/2016 11:16:22 AM; End time: 4/6/2016 11:16:22 AM; Duration: 0:00:00
            Processing Dimension Attribute 'Currency Key' completed.
                Start time: 4/6/2016 11:16:22 AM; End time: 4/6/2016 11:16:22 AM; Duration: 0:00:00

Errors and Warnings from Response
    Internal error: The operation terminated unsuccessfully.
    The following system error occurred:  The user name or password is incorrect. 
    Errors in the high-level relational engine. A connection could not be made to the data source with the DataSourceID of 'AdventureSource', Name of 'AdventureSource'.
    Errors in the OLAP storage engine: An error occurred while the dimension, with the ID of 'Dim Currency', Name of 'Dim Currency' was being processed.
    Errors in the OLAP storage engine: An error occurred while the 'Currency Key' attribute of the 'Dim Currency' dimension from the 'SampleCube2' database was being processed.
    Server: The current operation was cancelled because another operation in the transaction failed.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the error is:

> The user name or password is incorrect.

You fix it by correcting the user name and/or password.

Comment: It is likely the credentials on the data source (the relational database connection)

Comment: Yes, although the change could be needed there, or on the database side (permissions).